# Find the full solution of the equation of motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the general solution to the equation:

$\ddot{\phi} = [\Omega^2-\frac{g}{a}]\phi$

I know the answer but I need help understanding how it comes to be.
So what the solution says is that there are three cases:

Case 1: $\Omega^2 > \frac{g}{a}$ $\rightarrow$ $\phi(t)=A e^{\omega t}+Be^{-\omega t}$ , where $\omega^2 = \Omega^2 - \frac{g}{a}$

Case 2: $\Omega^2 < \frac{g}{a}$ $\rightarrow$ $\phi(t)=A e^{i\omega t}+Be^{-i\omega t}$ , where $\omega^2 = \frac{g}{a}-\Omega^2$

Case 3: $\Omega^2 = \frac{g}{a}$ $\rightarrow$ $\phi(t)=At+B$

Why do I need to look at these three cases and not just the usual:

$x(t) = Acos(\omega t) + Bsin(\omega t)$
?

And how do these three equations come to be?

Comment: You may look interesting the following video http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-005-highlights-of-calculus-spring-2010/derivatives/differential-equations-of-motion/

Comment: Should it not be $\ddot ϕ=[Ω^2-\frac ga]ϕ$? And $ ω^2=Ω^2−\frac ga$ resp. $ω=\sqrt{Ω^2−\frac ga}$? Please edit the question to correct the statements.

Comment: Yes LutzL, you are correct. It was just a few mistakes. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thanks mfl. That video is pretty good actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about the *sign* of the number in front of the $\phi$ on the right hand side of your first equation. Case 1, $\Omega^2>g/a$ means that the sign of that number is *positive*, Case 2 means it is *negative* and Case 3 means it is 0.
The "usual" solution you give corresponds to case 2, and we get some kind of harmonic motion.
Case 1 means that when you have differentiated the solution twice, you must end up with a *positive* multiple of your original function. The functions that satisfy this are $Ae^{\pm \omega t}$ so that the general solution is a linear combination of these.
Case 3 is possibly the simplest because it can be solved without guessing a solution; as $\Omega^2=g/a$, $\Omega^2-g/a = 0$ so that:
$${d^2 \phi \over dt^2}=0$$
$$\implies{d \phi \over dt} = A$$ where $A$ is some constant, and so integrating again gives
$$\phi = At+B$$
where $B$ is another constant to be determined from boundary conditions.

Comment: Very usefull, and thanks for the details. That really gave me the extra info I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be proved that the general solution to $u''+ a u =0$ is the linear combination $$C_1 e^{\lambda_1 x} + C_2 e^{\lambda_2 x}$$ where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the solution of the algebraic equation $\lambda^2 + a =0$. Hence you must consider three cases: (1) $a<0$, (2) $a=0$ and (3) $a>0$.

If $a>0$ you get a combination of sine and cosine because of the formula $$e^{it}=\cos t + i \sin t.$$

If $a=0$, you get $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$, but the constant function $e^{0\cdot x}=1$ is not the unique solution. It can be proved that $x \mapsto x$ can be used to get the general solution $C_1+C_2x$.

Comment: Very usefull, thank you.